# Where can I find release notes of magento enterprise edition version 1.11?

Tags: php, magento

Where can i find release notes of magento EE version 1.11 ? does it comes with magento package? I did not find it on http://www.magentocommerce.com

Answer (score 0):

Magento documentation for EE edition is provided for certified partners of magento.
It's not included in package.